# HTML5 Canvas: How to make a loading spinner by rotating the image in degrees?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation

I am making a loading spinner with html5 canvas. I have my graphic on the canvas but when i rotate it the image rotates off the canvas. How do I tell it to spin the graphic on its center point?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Canvas test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function() {
    var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('myDrawing');
    // Check the element is in the DOM and the browser supports canvas
    if(drawingCanvas && drawingCanvas.getContext) {
     // Initaliase a 2-dimensional drawing context
     var context = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');

     //Load the image object in JS, then apply to canvas onload     
     var myImage = new Image();
     myImage.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, 27, 27);
     }
     myImage.src = "img/loading.png";

     context.rotate(45);
    }
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas id="myDrawing" width="27" height="27">
  </canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but I question the value of using an executing piece of code to do something that an animated GIF which wouldn't tax the CPU unnecessarily can do. Especially during a load/processing point in your code.

Comment: @nissan there's nothing wrong with learning a new way to do something. this seems like a pretty simple exercise to learn the process.

Comment: i am overlaying a image over a video so a gif w/transparency will leave jagged edges. Animated pngs are not supported by all browsers that also support html5 video which is what this loader image will be overlayed on.

Comment: Benchmarks would be interesting. I came here because it seems mobile browsers stop animating .gifs while waiting for ajax calls. Kinda defeats the purpose of what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 28):

Here is the complete working example:)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Canvas Cog</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var cog = new Image();
            function init() {
                cog.src = 'data:image/png;base64,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'; // Set source path
                setInterval(draw,10);
            }
            var rotation = 0;
            function draw(){
                var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
                ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
                ctx.save();
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,27,27);
                ctx.translate(13.5,13.5); // to get it in the origin
                rotation +=1;
                ctx.rotate(rotation*Math.PI/64); //rotate in origin
                ctx.translate(-13.5,-13.5); //put it back
                ctx.drawImage(cog,0,0);
                ctx.restore();
            }
            init();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas width="27" height="27" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very cool. First time seeing an image embedded in javascript like this.

Comment: I hosted it at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drewnoakes/xF4m2/) so it's easy to check it out quickly.

Answer (score 5):

`rotate` turns the canvas(?) around your current position, which is 0, 0 to start. you need to "move" to your desired center point, which you can accomplish with

```
context.translate(x,y);
```

after you move your reference point, you want to center your image over that point. you can do this by calling

```
context.drawImage(myImage, -(27/2), -(27/2), 27, 27);
```

this tells the browser to start drawing the image from above and to the left of your current reference point, by have the size of the image, whereas before you were starting at your reference point and drawing entirely below and to the right (all directions relative to the rotation of the canvas).

since your canvas is the size of your image, your call to `translate` will use the same measurement, (27/2), for x and y coordinates.

so, to put it all together

```
// initialization:
context.translate(27/2, 27/2);

// onload: 
context.rotate(Math.PI * 45 / 180);
context.drawImage(myImage, -(27/2), -(27/2), 27, 27);
```

edit: also, rotation units are radians, so you'll need to translate degrees to radians in your code.

edits for rearranging stuff.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking into something like this, you might want to look at this script which does exactly what was originally being requested:
http://projects.nickstakenburg.com/spinners/

You can find the github source here:
https://github.com/staaky/spinners

He uses rotate, while keeping a cache of rectangles which slowly fade out, the older they are.

Answer (score 0):

I find another way to do html loading spinner. You can use sprite sheet animation. This approach can work both by html5 canvas or normal html/javascript/css. Here is a simple way implemented by html/javascript/css.

It uses sprite sheet image as background. It create a Javascript timer to change the background image position to control the sprite sheet animation. The example code is below. You can also check the result here: http://jmsliu.com/1769/html-ajax-loading-spinner.html

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
    <div class="spinner-bg">
        <div id="spinner"></div>
    </div>
    <style>
        .spinner-bg
        {
            width:44px;
            height:41px;
            background: #000000;
        }

        #spinner
        {
            width: 44px;
            height: 41px;
            background:url(./preloadericon.png) no-repeat;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var currentbgx = 0;
        var circle = document.getElementById("spinner");
        var circleTimer = setInterval(playAnimation, 100);

        function playAnimation() {
            if (circle != null) {
                circle.style.backgroundPosition = currentbgx + "px 0";
            }

            currentbgx -= 44; //one frame width, there are 5 frame
            //start from 0, end at 176, it depends on the png frame length
            if (currentbgx < -176) {
                currentbgx = 0;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```