# PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile on Android - 'Loading" screen

Tags: android, cordova

I've got a project using PhoneGap 1.0 and jQuery Mobile running on Android.

I'd like to achieve 2 outcomes:

1. When the app is loading and fetching data from the server, to put a splash screen. I've managed to put a splash screen for a defined time - but without really waiting for the data being loaded.
2. When the user hits the "refresh" button and the app tries to fetch data from the server - to put some "loading" screen. I wasn't able to achieve this. I've tried (http://nachbaur.com/blog/telling-your-user-that-a-phonegap-application-is-busy) but without success. I suspect it's only good for iOS.

Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the jQuery blockUI plugin?

http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

If you need a 'activity indicator' along with the UI block, try this:

[HTML5 Canvas: How to make a loading spinner by rotating the image in degrees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761100/html5-canvas-how-to-make-a-loading-spinner-by-rotating-the-image-in-degrees/2767556#2767556)

(since sadly, a simple animated GIF won't work...)

Answer (score 1):

I am using jQuery [BlockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/), with a simple spinner.gif image , works good on iOS, but on android the spinner freezes for some time  in between. But it works! I think it is important to use less processor speed as possible .