# How to animate polygon size in HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have drawn a polygon with the following code. Now I want to resize that polygon animatedly. In detail, I want to set an angular movement to one side of the polygon, such that it makes an arc, and so changes the size of polygon. I googled for everything regarding the polygon animation, but didn't get anything, though there is plenty of material for line animation.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
    var c=$('#myCanvas');
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle='#f00';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,40);
    ctx.lineTo(80,200);
    ctx.lineTo(100,200);
    ctx.lineTo(40,0);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
</script>
</div>
```

Is it possible to pick a line of a polygon and animate it, to change the shape of the polygon?

Comment: Not an answer, but *why* would you use jQuery (or some other library / framework) for that??

Comment: I don't know if there is a library design for this, but you could code the algorithm, for angular movement and then repaint the lines incident to that point.

Comment: Sure you can. _Don't_ hard-code the co-ordinates in - the canvas knows nothing other than pixels. As elRuLL said - put the mathematics that calculated the coordinates into the program. This will allow you to draw the same figure at different scales/translations/rotations. If on the other hand, you wish to change the shape - e.g animate from a square to a circle, then store an array of coordinates. Move them according to your need then clear-screen and redraw. Repeat ad-nauseum..

Comment: Not clear exactly what you're asking...Are you saying you want to animate a square to pentagon to hexagon?  If so, all sides would have to move during that morph.

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 - No, I could use javascript there, but this was just for the sake of explanation of the scene.

Comment: @markE - Yes that's almost what I am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is what I did and which has worked out:

```
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var dc     = canvas.getContext("2d");
var angle = 0;
var x = canvas.width;
var y = canvas.height;
window.setInterval(function(){
    angle = (angle + 1) % 360;
    dc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    dc.save();
    dc.fillStyle = "#DDDDDD";

    dc.translate(x/2,y);
    dc.rotate( angle*Math.PI/270 );  // rotate 90 degrees
    dc.translate(0,0);

    dc.beginPath();
    dc.moveTo(-x/16, 0);
    dc.lineTo(-x, y/2);
    dc.lineTo(-x/2,y);
    dc.lineTo(-0,y/16);
    dc.closePath();
    dc.fill();

    dc.restore();
}, 20);
</script>
```

I referred to Bill's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2767556/2163837 Thanks for your help also.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to store the coordinates of the polygon in an array and work on the numbers in that array instead.

Then render what you have in the array to canvas. Worry-free when it comes to translation and what-have-you.

See canvas as only a snapshot of whatever you have in the array at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

**Here’s how to turn a triangle into a square, a square into a pentagon, etc ….**

This code draws a regular polygon with the specified number of sides:

```
function drawPolygon(sideCount,size,centerX,centerY){

    // draw a regular polygon with sideCount sides
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo (centerX + size * Math.cos(0), centerY + size *  Math.sin(0));          
    for (var i = 1; i <= sideCount;i += 1) {
        var x=centerX + size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / sideCount);
        var y=centerY + size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / sideCount);
        ctx.lineTo (x, y);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();        

}
```

**Animating odd-sided polygons into even-sided polygons**

[image]

In this illustration, you can animate a triangle into a square by animating each colored vertex on the triangle to its corresponding position on the square.  All odd-sided polygons are transformed into even-sided polygons that same way.

**Animating even-sided polygons into odd-sided polygons**

[image]

In this illustration, you can animate a square into a pentagon by animating each colored vertex on the square to its corresponding position on the pentagon.  In this case, you have to also **cut the left-most yellow vertex in two** and animate the two portions to the two yellow vertices on the pentagon.  All even-sided polygons are transformed into odd-sided polygons that same way.

Here’s code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/DjV5f/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
    p{font-size:24px;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");


        //
        var colors=["","blue","green","black"];
        drawPolygon(3,50,70,70,2,"blue","red",colors,true);
        colors=["","blue","yellow","green","black"];
        drawPolygon(4,50,215,70,2,"blue","red",colors,false);
        //
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0,162);
        ctx.lineTo(300,162);
        ctx.stroke();
        //
        var colors=["black","blue","yellow","green"];
        drawPolygon(4,50,70,250,2,"blue","red",colors,true);
        colors=["black","blue","yellow","yellow","green"];
        drawPolygon(5,50,215,250,2,"blue","red",colors,false);


        function drawPolygon(sideCount,size,centerX,centerY,strokeWidth,strokeColor,fillColor,colorPts,showBursePoint){

            // draw a regular polygon with sideCount sides
            ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo (centerX +  size * Math.cos(0), centerY +  size *  Math.sin(0));          
            for (var i = 1; i <= sideCount;i += 1) {
                var x=centerX + size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / sideCount);
                var y=centerY + size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / sideCount);
                ctx.lineTo (x, y);
            }
            ctx.fillStyle=fillColor;
            ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
            ctx.lineWidth = strokeWidth;
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.restore();        

            // draw vertex points
            for (var i = 1; i <= sideCount;i += 1) {
                var x=centerX + size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / sideCount);
                var y=centerY + size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / sideCount);
                drawPoint(x,y,colorPts[i]);
            }

            // draw point where this poly will "burst" to create next poly
            if(showBursePoint){
                var burstX= centerX + size * Math.cos( Math.floor(sideCount/2) * 2 * Math.PI / sideCount);
                var burstY= centerY;
                drawPoint(burstX, burstY, "yellow");          
            }
        }

        function drawPoint(x,y,fill){
            ctx.save()
            ctx.strokeStyle="black";
            ctx.lineWidth=2;
            ctx.fillStyle=fill;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x,y,6,0,Math.PI*2,false);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.restore();
        }

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Regular polygons (3-8 sides)</p><br/>
    <p>Unmoving anchor point is green</p><br/>
    <p>Burst point is yellow</p><br/>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=350></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This was much inspiring.. Upvote.. Actually I'm trying to draw a flash emitting out of torch.. and want to rotate that flash's trajectory with respect to the angle created by mouse motion. yet to reach that rotation part.